# Expression to identify last element with no content after it

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have two different situations

CASE A

```
<cell>
   text here and there
   <break/>
   text here and there
   <break/>
</cell>
```

and CASE B

```
<cell>
   text here and there
   <break/>
   text here and there
   <break/>
   text here and there
</cell>
```

I need an Xpath condition that will select the last break in CASE A but not the one in CASE B so that I can remove it using XSLT

something of the sort

```
//cell/break[position() = last()]
```

will almost do the job but then I need to rule out those that have text behind them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
break[not(following-sibling::node())]
```

Comment: Works if the OP meant to select a `break` if it is the very last node before the parent element closes - but not if they meant to select the last break node that is not followed by a text node but may be followed by e.g. another element.

Comment: @MathiasMüller True, but OP said "*I have two different situations*". I have already gone beyond that by not settling for my original `break[not(following-sibling::text())]` which would have worked just fine, despite keshlam's comment.

Comment: Your original expression (same as mine) would have worked only if there were no line breaks and spaces in the input XML - which I doubt. But I agree, perhaps there is no need to generalize the solution.

Comment: @MathiasMüller It would have worked nevertheless - provided the stylesheet includes `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`. My fault for posting only the XPath.

Comment: +1 Agreed - would have been even more elegant than my overly complicated XPath.

Comment: I finally used the `break[not(following-sibling::text()]` it worked great on my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Use an expression like:

```
break[position() = last() and not(following-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.) != ''])]
```

In plain English, it means:

> Select the last `break` element in the context - but only if it is *not* followed by a text node other than one that only contains whitespace.

As suggested by @keshlam, the last condition is necessary because line breaks are text nodes, too. But a text node that only contains whitespace will equal `""` when `normalize-space()` is applied to it.

Assuming the following input:

**Input 1**

```
<cell>
   text here and there
   <break/>
   text here and there
   <break type="wrong"/>
   text here and there
</cell>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="break[position() = last() and not(following-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.) != ''])]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will (correctly) yield no output. On the other hand,

**Input 2**

```
<cell>
   text here and there
   <break/>
   text here and there
   <break type="correct"/>
</cell>
```

yields:

**Output 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<break type="correct"/>
```

Comment: That may not quite work, since in fact there is a text following-sib in both cases: the line-break whitespace.

Comment: @keshlam You are right, thanks for spotting this! I have edited my answer to account for this.